# How do I get email alerts from HP ILO 2?

Tags: ilo

I have a server with Integrated Lights-Out 2 Advanced for remote management.  On the Dell machines I've used with DRAC it was easy to specify an IP that has a an email server on it so I could recieve alerts.  I don't see this in the HP iLO.  I see stuff for SNMP, if I need to use that, how? The server is running ESX.

Thanks.
PA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The iLO management controller can't send e-mail directly itself. The intention is that one configures an SNMP monitoring service and then configures iLO to send SNMP traps to that which in turn can send emails.